# Exposing a Docker database service only on the internal network with Traefik

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, traefik

Let's say I defined two services "frontend" and "db" in my `docker-compose.yml` which are deployed to a Docker swarm, i.e. they may also run in different stacks. With this setup Traefik automatically generates the frontend and backend for each stack which is fine.

Now I have another Docker container running temporarily in a Jenkins pipeline which shall be able to access the `db` service in a specific stack. My first idea was to expose the `db` service by adding it to the `cluster-global-net` network so that Traefik can generate a frontend route to the bakend. This basically works.

But I'd like to hide the database service from "the public" while still being able to connect another Docker container to it via its stack or service name using the internal "default" network.

Can this be done somehow?

```
version: '3.6'

networks:
  default: {}
  cluster-global-net:
    external: true

services:
  frontend:
    image: frontend_image
    ports:
    - 8080
    networks:
    - cluster-global-net
    - default
    deploy:
      labels:
        traefik.port: 8080
        traefik.docker.network: cluster-global-net
        traefik.backend.loadbalancer.swarm: 'true'
        traefik.backend.loadbalancer.stickiness: 'true'
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any

  db:
    image: db_image
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=false
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=db_schema
    - MYSQL_USER=db_user
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=db_pass
    ports:
    - 3306
    volumes:
    - db_volume:/var/lib/mysql
    networks: 
    - default
    restart: on-failure
    deploy:
      labels:
        traefik.port: 3306
        traefik.docker.network: default
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a network on which both of them are deployed, but that it's not visible from anyone else.

To do such, create a network , add it to your db service and frontend, and also to your temporary service. And indeed, remove traefik label on db because they are not needed anymore here.

EG :

```
...
networks:
  default: {}
  cluster-global-net:
    external: true
  db-net:
    external: true

services:
  frontend:
    image: frontend_image
    networks:
    - cluster-global-net
    - default
    - db-net
    deploy:
        ...

  db:
    image: db_image
    ...
    networks: 
    - default
    - db-net
    restart: on-failure
    #no labels
```

```
docker network create db-net 
docker stack deploy -c <mycompose.yml> <myfront>
docker service create --network db-net <myTemporaryImage> <temporaryService>
```

Then, the temporaryService as well as the frontend can reach the db through *db:3306*

BTW : you don't need to open the port for the frontend, since traefik will access it internally (trafik.port).

**EDIT** : new exemple with network created from compose file.

```
...
networks:
  default: {}
  cluster-global-net:
    external: true
  db-net: {}

services:
  frontend:
    image: frontend_image
    networks:
    - cluster-global-net
    - default
    - db-net
    deploy:
        ...

  db:
    image: db_image
    ...
    networks: 
    - default
    - db-net
    restart: on-failure
    #no labels
```

```
docker stack deploy -c <mycompose.yml> someStackName
docker service create --network someStackName_db-net <myTemporaryImage> <temporaryService>
```

Comment: Defining `db-net` as external is necessary so that the temporary service can connect because it is not defined in the compose file?

Comment: no, it is not. The only drawback, if you create it from your compose and later use it from outside of the compose is that you will have to reference it as stackname_db-net.

Comment: That's ok as I have control over the stack name. Will try your solution...

Comment: When running my container with `docker run --network=stackName_db-net` I get the following message: `docker: Error response from daemon: network stackName_db-net not found.`

Comment: I guess the "stackName" is not litterally used here. Can you check the result of docker network ls after you created the stack (you also can read the actual name of the network after you created the stack)

Comment: Yes, the "stackName" is used as a placeholder here. Using Portainer I can see that the network name has been set to "stackName_db-net". It's an overlay network.

Comment: THen this should work. Can you try creating the network separatly, as a test

Comment: What I haven't understood so far: Is the setting `external: true` mandatory for this case? My current setup does not have this setting.

Comment: No : external:true is not mandatory if you create the network from within the compose. I'll add another exemple in my answer

Comment: Does it maybe matter on which machine this temporary container is running? Maybe it must be started on one of the Docker swarm nodes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188472/discussion-between-marvin-and-robert-strauch).

Comment: It tuend out that our Jenkins server is not running in the Docker swarm. That's why a container started from Jenkins cannot connect to the network. I accepted this answer because it would work otherwise.